# Why openmodelica give me this array dimension error?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm developing a system in modelica and i have a big problem.
When i run the simulation in terminal, it display this error:
"Dimension 2 has bounds 1...3, got array subscript 0".
I suppose that an array declaration have an index out of bound, but no one of them have it. I don't know what to do. I'll leave the code here, i hope someone can help me
https://github.com/BigMautone/Drones.git
**probably, the error is located in psoControllor.mo or drone.mo or collisionAvoidance.mo or System.mo**

Comment: Which model? Running System in Dymola just works, without any similar error messages; so it might be some odd issue in OpenModelica. But in general I would use a record constant K is instead of a record class, and also add a package.mo containing "package Drones end Drones;" so that you can load everything at once.

Comment: I'm not pretty confident with openmodelica, so i think that use a record class for store all constants i need was a good idea. I'll check what is a record constant and i will add the package.
Anyway, i don't know which model give me this error, but i thought it was one of the 4 listed in the main question

Comment: I can reproduce your error by running omc run.mos. Seems like you hit a bug. I will investigate more and open a bug report.

Comment: Thank you Adrian. I really can't solve it, i'm debbuging since February 1st without any achievment...

Comment: I just found out that in modelica you can't do operation with matrix and scalar. Anyway, the documentation write the opposite, but i fixed it!